# check if file exists before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, file

I have an upload modal with simple file input. If the user selects a file then it gets deleted and the user hits upload I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "[servername]" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

form code:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="@Url.Action("Function", "Controller")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
..form code
</form>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

and its failing in the jquery load function:

```
$("iframe").load(function () {

iframeContents = this.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
...rest of code
```

as far as I can tell it doesn't like the .document potion

Is there anyway to ensure that the file still exists between selecting it for upload and submitting the form to the controller. Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized that when i originally was checking the file size i was checking the size of the file name not size of the file. Here es the final fix

```
if ($('#File').get(0).files[0].size === 0) {
    window.alert("missing file");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the JavaScript File API and checking the size of the file through the object's size property?

Comment: I can't add a new API to the project until its fully vetted. I'll add it in locally and see if it works though